# User named "System" class messes up System.out.println

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a class named System, however, when I tried using System.out.println in other classes, it returns the error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'out'". I assumed that the System class I created is used instead of the actual System class in the Java language package. Is there a way to make Intellij uses the System class in Java language, or this is just a normal class's name contradiction and I should not use name like "System" for any user-made classes at all?

Comment: You can reference `java.lang.System` by using `java.lang.System.out.println(...)`. However, I would not recommend naming your own class System. In other words, this is using the fully qualified name of the System class that is used for printing to access its methods.

Comment: While this is not on SO, it will give an answer to your question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131499/what-are-the-reasons-one-would-use-fully-qualified-class-names-in-source-code

Comment: get creative... if possible name your class something else to resolve this conflict.

Comment: *"I have a class named `System` ..."* - well there's your problem!  The best solution is to rename your `System` class.  (What you are seeing is standard Java language semantics.  Not the IDE's doing.)   It is a bad idea to declare a custom class whose name collides with any class in the `java.lang` package.

Comment: well changing the class's name would be too simple, so I got curious and want to know what other alternatives do we have here.

Comment: *"changing the class's name would be too simple"* - The secret to banging your head against a brick wall is knowing when to stop :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your import statements. You are likely importing your own `System` class into the class file. If so, any time you reference just `System`, that class file will use your import.

If you insist on using "System" for your own class name (which is not necessarily recommended), you can always use the fully-qualified `java.lang.System.out.println()` in your code instead.

My recommendation would be to rename your `System` class to something different. Personally, I use a `Utility` class in my projects to provide custom methods that may fall under a "System-like" category.

While there are certainly exceptions, a good general rule is to not name your own classes the same as any classes found in the `java.lang` project. Those classes are so integral to the Java language that you'll likely only cause confusion for yourself and anyone else trying to read and understand your code.